# como ejecutar una operacion matematica que esta en una variable de tipo cadena

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy realizando una calculadora con javascript, y cada vez que se le da click a un numero u operador estos se anexan a una variable de tipo cadena con el fin de que al darle click al boton de igual o resultado ejecute la operacion que se haya puesto en la varible como por ejemplo esta:

```
var operaciones="10+5-8*5"
```

pero el detalle es que no se como ejecutar esa operación, es decir intento convertirla a entero o flotante y no da, solo imprime el primer numero antes del primer operador que halla, en este caso solo imprime el 10 y eso no es lo que necesito, necesito de alguna forma convertir esa operacion y ejecutarla

gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `eval` que ejecutaría tu operación directamente desde tu string

```js
var operaciones="10+5-8*5"
console.log(eval(operaciones))
```

Comment: ufff meeen, exactamente era lo que estaba buscando EXACTAMENTE ESO!!! MUCHAS GRACIAS, crack, titan, mata demonios, anticristo :v. gracias de nuevo @Israel

Comment: Sería adecuado mencionar que el uso de `eval` es peligroso, debido a los problemas de seguridad por llegar a evaluar cualquier cadena, lo que puede dar pie entre otras cosas, a vulnerabilidades XSS. Puedes comenzar a comprobar o leer más sobre el tema [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)